# android inappbrowser singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport FASLE

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I admit defeat and have decided to post on here to see if anyone can help.
I am building a PhoneGap application, v:2.9.0. It also incorporates jquery mobile.
The application has been completed and released on IOS with no problems. On Android i am one bug away from success.
Basically i have a number of links to external resources which are using the cordova inappbrowser to open the link within the app. I am using jquery to bind to the links click event and stao its default behaviour and load the link using the inappbrowser. This works fine in IOS but i get this error in android:
singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE

The code for the links is below, can anyone help?

```
$(function() {
    $('.weblink').click( function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        openLink(url)

    }); 

});
function openLink(url){
    window.open(url, '_blank','location=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes');

}
```